# How to deploy OpenShift Java EE application locally?

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, openshift

I'd like to know how to deploy an OpenShift Java EE application locally, to speed up the development process, and only push to GIT when necessary.

1. Do I need to change anything in the POM? (Custom build?) If so, how to tell the IDE/OpenShift which one to use?
2. How do I set up multiple persistence.xml files? (One for local SQL,
   and one for OpenShift SQL  - e.g.: IP address of DB server)

Thank you in advance.

EDIT: I'm using Eclipse Mars if that matters (for example if JBossTools OpenShift 2 plugin can ease it somehow).

Comment: Openshift is a cloud based application development and hosting platform, so why you want it locally. These links might be helpful to understand about openshift https://developers.openshift.com/ and https://dzone.com/articles/openshift-how-create-web-0

Comment: I understand that, but I'm using it as a free Tomcat hosting. I'd like to do the development locally, so it doesn't take 5 minutes to see how changing a line affects the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is a standard operation, even if you present it reversed. The common usage, is to first setup a local dev environment (IDE, tools, tomcat or jetty), build a war, run it locally, and only then deploy it to the hosting service - ok if you have not taken provisions for the hosting interface, that last operation is likely to break ;-)

As you are using OpenShift that uses git + maven to deploy java application, it is reasonably easy:

- you must first design the global architecture of your web app, identifying the OpenShift dependances (database, ...)
- you then setup your git system with two distinct branches, one containing OpenShift configuration, the latter containing your local configuration
- you normally develop localy
- when you have a (at least running even if not finished) version you push it to the OpenShift branch and then to the OpenShift platform

The magic here comes from the ability of git to keep branches differing only by some files in sync.

Comment: That looks ridiculously easy after thinking it through, I don't know why I overcomplicated it. Thank you very much. :)